# C# Client-Server implementation error on client's socket "no connection could be made..."

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to launch my client, but have an error. Server is already running on the same computer. So I'm using "localhost" with GetHostEntry:

```
 IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
 IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
 IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);

Sock = new Socket(remoteEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Sock.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), Sock);
```

But I have this "no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it":

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:7777
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at NotifierClient.AsynchronousClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in *** :line 156
```

Line 156 is

```
client.EndConnect(ar);
```

What is the reason? Could it be because ipHostInfo.AddressList[0] is an IPv6? How then I can accept Ipv4 address?

Comment: Could it be that your firewall is blocking it?

Comment: I think no. The server is working OK. And VS has a permission to use network

Comment: BTW I can simply connect via telnet to my server

Comment: @KSice - Please see the edit to my answer below

Comment: @Ksice I just want to make sure that the server is running and is accepting connection and on the correct Port. Can you show any of the server code just to make sure. Normally that error code occurs when I'm not running the server or I get the IP address/Port wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [AddressFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily.aspx) property of the IPAddress class to tell whether the address is IPv4 or IPv6.

This way you can loop through the list of IPAddress-es returned and choose the first one that is an IPv4 address:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");    

IPAddress ipAddress = null;
foreach(var addr in ipHostInfo.AddressList)
{
    if(addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)        // this is IPv4
    {
         ipAddress = addr;
         break;
    }
}

// at this point, ipAddress is either going to be set to the first IPv4 address
//  or it is going to be null if no IPv4 address was found in the list
if(ipAddress == null)
    throw new Exception("Error finding an IPv4 address for localhost");

IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);

Sock = new Socket(remoteEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Sock.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), Sock);
```

Comment: @Ksice - You're not doing it right, please see the edit to my answer

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Thanks! This helped!

Comment: @Ksice - I'm glad it worked out for you.. If this answered your question please upvote/mark as answer!

Answer (score -1):

What I use for localhost for IPV4:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
```

Comment: that code could back-fire for you. There is no guarantee that the IPv4 address will be listed second.. Even worse, there is no guarantee that an IPv4 address will even be present!